# HTML5 Position Sticky Couldn't work although i had set top 0

Tags: html, css

```css
/* site navigation bar */

nav.sitenavigation {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  clear: both;
  text-align: center;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  background-color: #f0f8ff;
  margin: 50px auto;
}

nav.sitenavigation p {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding-right: 5em;
}

nav.sitenavigation a:link,
nav.sitenavigation a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000000;
}

nav.sitenavigation a:hover,
nav.sitenavigation a:focus {
  color: #33cc00;
}
p{
margin: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <nav class="sitenavigation">
      <p><a href="index.html">&#127968; Home</a></p>
      <p><a href="listing.html">&#x1f4d6; Item Listing</a></p>
      <p><a href="order.html">&#128722; Your Order</a></p>
      <p><a href="contactus.html">&#x260E; Contact Us</a></p>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <p>ABC
  </p>
</body>
```

I have tried many ways to let my navigation bar to be stick on top but it is not. I have reset the HTML style to be overflow: auto. It shows like position: relative instead of position: sticky

Comment: The snippet does not demonstrate the problem. But `position:sticky` makes an element only sticky as long as its parent element is visible on the screen. As an example, I made [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/txc4Luyp/) that shows the stickyness working fine as long as some of the div content is visible, but it scrolls up with the div after that. Is that what happens in your case?

Comment: It doesn't stick on top at all.

Comment: remove the div around the navigation and it will work

Comment: @MrLister there is an extra div in his code which create the issue, the element is sticking to that div but the height of the div is also defined by the sticky element so  there is no room for the sticky effect.

Comment: @TemaniAfif  Thanks a lot. It's the div causing the sticky in nav not working

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yes, that's what I demonstrated with my fiddle.

Answer (score 2):

`position: sticky` works on when height is enough long.

Can you make `div` (which in just below on `body`) to `div style="height: 1000px;"`?

In my case, that style works well.

Comment: I have added the margin 2000px to demonstrate the problem

Answer (score 0):

Set height for a relative container

```css
/* site navigation bar */
body {height: 800rem;}
nav.sitenavigation {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 1.4em;
    background-color: #f0f8ff;
    margin: 50px auto;
}
nav.sitenavigation p{
     display: inline-block;
     margin: 0.5em;
     padding-right: 5em;
}
nav.sitenavigation a:link, nav.sitenavigation a:visited{
     text-decoration: none;
     color: #000000;
}
nav.sitenavigation a:hover, nav.sitenavigation a:focus{
     color: #33cc00;
}
```

```html
<body>

        <nav class="sitenavigation">
                <p><a href="index.html">&#127968; Home</a></p>
                <p><a href="listing.html">&#x1f4d6; Item Listing</a></p>
                <p><a href="order.html">&#128722; Your Order</a></p>
                <p><a href="contactus.html">&#x260E; Contact Us</a></p>
        </nav>

      </body>
```

Answer (score -1):

The position relative you're seeing would be correct as per definition:

> A sticky element toggles between relative and fixed, depending on the
>   scroll position. It is positioned relative until a given offset
>   position is met in the viewport - then it "sticks" in place (like
>   position:fixed). https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_positioning.asp

If your navigation is supposed to stick on top, regardless of the scrolling, you most probably want to use position: absolute instead